# Duplicated output from Twit (NPM module & Twitter API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twitter, socket.io

I'm building a portfolio website and I want to integrate a live Twitter feed. I'm using Node, Socket.IO, Express, and Twit. I have the stream working and outputting the tweets to the page, but when the client refreshes or disconnects and reconnects the tweets are then duplicated, as in I receive multiples of the same tweet. The server side of the code is connecting to the Twitter API using Twit to get a stream from Twitter's public stream containing all tweets about a supplied hashtag, and then sending them to the client using `io.sockets.emit()`.

What I think is happening is the client is still connected and receiving the tweets, then on reconnect receives them again.

Here is my backend code and further down my client side code (planning on refactoring this to multiple modules). Pictures supplied at the bottom.

Thanks for the help on this, I have been having a blast with Node so far!

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(3000);

//To Do refactor
app.get('/style.css', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/style.css");
});

app.get('/feed.html', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/feed.html");
});

app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});

app.get('/contact.html', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/contact.html");
});

app.get('/work.html', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/work.html");
});

app.get('/social.html', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/social.html");
});

app.get('/about.html', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/about.html");
});

var Twit = require('twit');
var watchList = ['#USA'];
 var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         ''
  , consumer_secret:      ''
  , access_token:         ''
  , access_token_secret:  ''
})

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('Connected');

 var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: watchList });

  stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
    if(tweet.text !== undefined){
      //console.log(tweet.text);
       io.sockets.emit('stream',tweet.text);
    }
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('Disconnected');
  });

 });
```

Here is my client side code:

```
<script>
          var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
          var count = 0;

          socket.on('stream', function(tweet){       
          if(count < 10)   {
            $('#tweetd').append(tweet + '<br>');
            count++;
            //console.log(count)
          }
        });
  </script>
 <div id="tweetd"></div>
</div>
```

[image: This is on the first connection]

[image: This is what is looks like on the reconnection]

Comment: I'll work on this some more and see if I can find a solution for it. I'm sure this is a little tough for someone to test because they have to get an API key from Twitter to test it. I'll see if maybe I can get a temporary API key.